# How can I make concentric circles as grid for a polar plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

But I need to delimitate the circles for x, y in `[-2,6]`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow!10, fill=hkvbluelogo!5](-2, -2) rectangle (6, 6);
\foreach \s in {0, 1, 2} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) circle (\s + 0.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (\s);
  \draw [thick,color=red,domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius=\s );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want the circles drawn only over the gray part.

[image]

Comment: use clip to remove the unwanted part

Comment: @JLDiaz Do you want to answer?

Comment: Clip was the tool I needed and I did it. But, I think you can post an answer for other users whom may need it

Answer (score 1):

Use `\clip <path>;` as the first command inside a `scope` environment containing the content to be clipped away (in this case, the circles).

The clipping path can be an arbitrary path, but it cannot have any additional style options set, which is why we cannot re-use the colored rectangle drawn elsewhere.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow!10, fill=blue!10](-2, -2) rectangle (6, 6);
\begin{scope}
\clip (-2, -2) rectangle (6, 6);
\foreach \s in {0, 1, 2} {
  \draw [lightgray] (0,0) circle (\s + 0.5);
  \draw (0,0) circle (\s);
  \draw [thick,color=red,domain=0:2*pi,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius=\s );
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]